# I sent someone an .ai file, but they can't edit it. What do I do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I sent someone an .ai file for them to edit. She said that when she scrolls over something with her mouse, each item is specifically highlighted, but when she clicks on it to edit it, everything is selected. The answer is probably very easy. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ungroup or release clipping mask?

Comment: Try sending an EPS file or ask what version they have and save for that version of Illustrator.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the objects are grouped together or, more likely, enclosed in a clipping mask. Illustrator tends to do that when opening files saved from earlier versions (for ex. version CS6 opening a file saved from CC 2015 as a backward-compatible file).

To edit the objects separately, one has to 1) ungroup the objects or 2) double click the group to enter in *isolation mode*.

Comment: You can also check the layers panel, and go into a group and select objects manually that way.

Comment: Thank you this has been very helpful